# Can't select anything in object mode in Layout mode

Tags: selection-tools

[image: Layout mode, objects remain unselectable]

[image: In Modeling mode, I can select any object]

I don't know why I can't select objects in Layout mode. The only way I can select an object is by clicking where its Origin is and when I do, I get an orange outline rather than yellow. My second image is from Modeling mode, where I can click and select any object and I get a yellow outline.

[image]

Comment: Hello, maybe you have selected your armature and you are in Edit mode? But maybe show a screenshot of the whole interface?

Comment: Yes, please show the complete interface. Seeing the rest of viewport and the objects in there, the outliner and the menu bars will give us much more information of what is going on than just a closeup of one selected object.

Comment: Hi @moonboots
I just added a full screenshot of my layout.

Comment: I'm not sure what's the problem, could you please share your file?

Comment: @moonboots
I'm trying to upload to Blender Stack Exchange but my file is 63MB and I don't know how to get it down smaller. I uploaded the blend file here to my Google Drive:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10ib443D_y9zfO7_fVN-zPmT15zDJ6Aj7/view?usp=share_link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are in *Select Circle* mode, switch to *Select Box*, which is more common:

[image]